# Browser popup window in angular2 application with mvc

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, model-view-controller

I am a asp.net developer and currently analysing our existing asp.net web form application to migrate in new client side technology using "`MVC with angular2 and Web Api`".

In my existing asp.net web form application the login and landing (dashboard page after login) open in main browser window other than this all pages are opening as a browser popup window when user clicks on menu, hyper links or buttons, this was the client requirement and they still need same behaviour in new technology as well.

During my study to implement "`MVC, angular2 and Web Api`" I found some comments like using browser popup window in (SPA) angular2 application is against its concept! even I did not found a single example in angular2 application to open a popup window for same application page! can some one help me on this? I am unable to take decisions to start implementation due to this issue, as the basic need of my application is browser popup window.

We are opening screens like this in popup.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details around what you are doing with the pop-ups? How were you opening them before?

Comment: Are you looking for a modal popup window? You can look at using a library for this... ngx-bootstrap is a good one to consider.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel, To provide the fast interaction with the application entities we have provided the facility to open multiple browser window so user can work on multiple screens at a time like in our application user opened a policy screen at same time he needs to check their claims so need not to close the policy screen he can open a claims screen in separate window and work on both screens at a time. We are opening a popup window in existing application using window.open javascript function like this.

Comment: "window.open('claims.aspx', 'claims', "height=" + windowHeight + ", width=" + windowWidth + ", resizable=yes, menubar=no; toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes");

Comment: @pixelbits, I am not looking to open modal popup, I am simpaly looking to open a new browser window in popup, which will show the page of my application.

Comment: Is there a problem that you are running into doing the same thing in your Angular app right now? I see no technical reason why you shouldn't be able to do the same thing.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel, I am not getting any reference sample code to open a browser popup window using angular2, I got some links in angular1 but they are opening a external domain page like "google.com" etc, as well as angular2 is totally deiffrent than angular1. so here in ng2 I am not getting the basic object by using that to open a popup, if you have any reference code please post it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Opening the pop-up would be the same as you were doing in your previous system (meaning same `window.open` stuff). The content in the window is from the URL for the first property (doesn't matter if it is claims.aspx from your old system, google.com, or a route in your Angular app - the browser is just simply loading that URL). Can you provide some more specific information in your question about the workflow your old system had? How did modifying those entities in the pop-up affect the main window (e.g. how did the entities get updated on the UI, etc)?

Comment: You won't get much more help than somebody posting code to open google.com without giving more details. Unfortunately I'm not by a computer at the moment to throw an example together to show you (on my phone at the moment), but I'll check back later to see if I can offer any more help.